# Is there a way to show whole database first at search page (postgres)?

Tags: database, postgresql, search

I wrote class for searching the database on Wildflyusing postgresql and  I write in Red Hat Core Studio. It works, but now I would like it to show all the database already when I come to search page. Like if I would click Search button with empty fields. With added text in search fields you could narrow the search. 
Also is there a safer (less hackable) way to do search than
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MYDATABASE (WHERE _____ LIKE _____) ? Now I am working on public database, but I would like also to write programs for private databases.

For example: MYDATABASE includes elements:

Id      Code        LatinName

1       CUL         Culicoides spp

2       COL         Coleophora

3       APH         Aphidoiea

4       PHF         Phoridae

5       COLD        Coldeatum

When I come on search page, I see all the elements. If I write CUL in code I only get one result. If I write COLD I get two results

I am still fairly new in programming.

Code is:

```
public void searchButton() {
ResultSet ps = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection con = getConnection();
        int parameters = 0;
String srm = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MYDATABASE";
        if( getCode() != null && !"".equals(getCode()) ) 
            parameters ++;
if( getLatinName() != null && !"".equals(getLatinName()) ) 
            parametri ++;
if(parametri >0) {
            srm = srm + " WHERE ";
            if( getCode() != null && !"".equals(getCode()) ) {
                parameters --;
                srm = srm +"(code LIKE '%" + getCode() + "%' OR code LIKE '" + getCode() + "%')";
}
            if( getCode() != null && !"".equals(getCode()) && getLatinName() != null && !"".equals(getLatinName()) ) srm = srm + " AND ";
            if( getLatinName() != null && !"".equals(getLatinName()) ) {
                parameters --;
                srm = srm + "latin_name LIKE ('%" + getLatinName() + "%' or '" + getLatinName() + "%')";
}
        }
String stm=srm.toUpperCase();
try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement(srm);
            pst.execute();
            ps = pst.getResultSet();

            while(ps.next()) {
                Item thing = new Item();
                thing.setId(ps.getInt(1));
                thing.setCode(ps.getString(4));
                thing.setLatinName(ps.getString(2));        
                table.add(thing);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

If I forgot something important please let me know, so I can add it.

Comment: If you have no search criteria then don't add any search criteria. You'll also want to look into SQL injection (recall the tale of Little Bobby Tables). "Better way to search" is nebulous; better how?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "come to the search page". Seems the code you have is a completed search page. Also explain exactly what you mean by "show all the database". Again your code looks like it queries 1 table. Further it would be one thing to show an entire database consisting of say 10 tables and 1000's of rows, but an entirely different thing for a database of 1000 tables and 10's of billion rows.

Comment: Thank you both for good comments. With better I meant less vulnerable to hack. This database would be public but I would like also to learn working with databases that would be private. As I read about searching in SQL SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MYDATABASE (WHERE _____ LIKE _____) is hackable and I don't like it.